# In operator in 2D lists

Tags: python, list, 2d, operator-keyword

I am having trouble utilizing the in operator with 2D lists. In the following code, I expect 'hi' to be printed but 'bye' is printed. Shouldn't the statement "if '@' in tempGen:" return 'True' and move on, or am I misunderstanding how the in operator functions.

```
MAX_ROW = 5
MAX_COL =5

tempGen = ['@'] * MAX_ROW
for row in range(MAX_ROW):
    tempGen[row] = ['@'] * MAX_COL
print(tempGen)

if '@' in tempGen:
    print('hi')
else:
    print('bye')
```

I can't seem to find any answers to this question, but if you know of a thread please link me. Thank you for any help.

Comment: `in` doesn't recurse down your data structure, it looks like you just need `if any('@' in t for t in tempGen):`

Comment: @AChampion. Ok that works. I'm still new to python, so if you don't mind could you explain why 'in' can recurse down 1d lists but not 2d lists. why is 'any()' unnecessary for 1d lists?

Comment: `in` is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) to check if the value is in the container, it is largely equivalent to (for lists) `any(v == e for e in lst)` - but don't do this just use the `in` operator (other containers very efficient implementations of `in`).